# Creating a form based on a :has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, nested-forms, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I am new to ruby and I am trying to put together a form that will allow you to add items to an order. The form will need to take a quantity for each item in the order.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :restaurant
   has_many :selections
   has_many :items, :through =>:selections;
end

class Selection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
  has_many :selections
  has_many :orders, :through => :selections
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :menus
  has_many :items, :through => :menus
end

class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :items
end
```

**order controller**

```
# GET /orders/new
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @restaurant.items.all.each do |item|
    @order.selections.build
  end
end
```

**orders/_form.html.erb** :

The form is supposed to list out the available items and allow you to enter the quantity for an item.

```
<%= form_for [@restaurant,@order], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
   <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :current_table, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
         <%= f.text_field :current_table, :class => 'text_field' %>
      </div>
   </div>

   <% f.fields_for :selections do |ff| %>
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= ff.label :quantity, :class => 'control-label' %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= ff.text_field :quantity, :class => 'text_field' %>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end%>

   <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                    course_orders_path, :class => 'btn' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to render the page I get the following error:

```
undefined method `quantity' for
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Selection:0x007ffa0287cd60>
```

I realize this is probably because I haven't initialized any selections but I'm not entirely sure how/where I should do that. When the form is submitted I want to create an order with a selection for each of the non-empty quantities.

So my first question is how do I construct my form so that I can take a quantity for each item that I know about?

Do I need to initialize anything in the order controller to make this work?

Can you give me any advice or point me to a tutorial that shows me how to set up the create method of the order controller?

EDIT:

I added some code to the Order controller and the form, so when I render the page I no longer get an error, but none of my 'selection' fields rendered. I confirmed with some logging and the debugger that I correctly 'build' 4 selections so I would expect those form elements show up.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `@order.selections` is an array, probably you can't get it's property (perhaps defined for one model - selection). Also post your Restaurant model to make it clear with dependencies.

Comment: I added my restaurant and menu models.

Comment: how come you don't have `has_many :orders` in your restaurant model?

Comment: @WaliAli That was probably a mistake. My migration for creating orders has a t.belongs to :restaurant. That didn't appear to be causing my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :nested_class
```

somewhere?

Also, I had to do something like

```
<%= form_for [@restaurant,@order] do |f| %>
...
  <%= f.fields_for :selections, @order.selections do |ff| %>
  ...
  <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```